# How to extract concrete url with Regex from a block of text written in html in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following block of text:

```
<div class="view view-views-fichas view-id-views_fichas view-display-id-block_4 view-dom-id-a77b24219bd9d1b93008f7ac4fac8979">



  <div class="view-content">


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- CALL: theme('views_view_unformatted') -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'profiles/tema/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view-unformatted.tpl.php' -->
  <div>


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- CALL: theme('views_view_fields') -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'profiles/tema/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view-fields.tpl.php' -->

      /textname%C3%B3n-name-test/13-theme/020-alecl%C3%B3n-more-text-in-theme/03-more-and-more-text
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'profiles/tema/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view-fields.tpl.php' -->

</div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'profiles/tema/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view-unformatted.tpl.php' -->

</div>
```

The text that I need to extract is the one that says:
`/textname%C3%B3n-name-test/13-theme/020-alecl%C3%B3n-more-text-in-theme/03-more-and-more-text`

I have the following example:
[Link to regex php](https://regex101.com/r/AAXLQT/1)

Thanks..

Comment: Things will be much easier if you run this through `strip_tags` first and just use that regex on the plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably easier to what you're doing right now:

```
$text = strip_tags($html);
preg_match("/((?:\/(?:[0-9a-z-._~:?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=`.]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+)+)/i",$text,$matches);
```

That list of characters is characters permitted in a URL segment.

Example:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a3893cb4cb820b6ed40be9f43023e8b9a2869383

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
/textname\S+
```

with e.g. `~` as delimiters, see [**your modified demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/AAXLQT/1).